# EWS - OnNotificationEvent => which fields were modified?

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm getting streaming notifications from folder: 'Calendar' by using the EWS Managed API.
I have subscribed to EventTypes: Created, Moved, Modified, and Deleted.
When I get a notification where the EventType = Modified, I can read values like ItemId and ChangeKey.

My question: Is it possible to find out which fields were modified?
Or can I somehow get the previous version of the calendar item (before modified)?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its expected in the instance that you are synchronizing changes that you would have a local version to compare any changes against. On Exchange under the recoverableItems Non_IPM_Subtree folder there is Calendar Logging folder that does store information about changes made to the calendar items but this is meant for Calendar repair/diagnostics rather then synchronization.

Comment: I do have a local version to compare against, and that is usually good enough. My challenge is: if I do a local change on the start time, and EWS for some reason can't reach the exchange server, I would have 2 different start times at this point. In my experience, I can see that o365 sends notifications for item modifications at unexpected times. This might then result in exchange updating my local version with wrong (old) start time. I do compare "LastModifiedTime", but this is now changed to current time in exchange. So I'm trying to find out why we get these notifications => what changed?

Comment: If I do a local change on the start time, and EWS for some reason can't reach the exchange server. When you do an UpdateItem if the update was successful you should get back a new changekey if you don't get that you update hasn't worked. The ChangeKey is generally better to track in addition to LastModifiedTime